# Kubuntu 14.04 won't reboot after updates

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown

I noticed I had a bunch of updates come through the other day that required a restart.  When I went to restart it just takes me to a user login screen.  In the lower right there are options to restart and shutdown.  Neither of those buttons work, specifically, clicking on them does nothing.  The only thing I can do is log back in.

From there I opened a terminal and did `sudo shutdown -h now` which returned `command not found`

I did `whereis shutdown` and it came back with `/etc/shutdown.sh` but that shell script just contains `shutdown -h now`.

It seems my shutdown binary is gone.  I did `sudo find -name shutdown` and it came back with `/home/dean/.kde/shutdown` but that is a folder not a file.

What should I do?

Comment: It's a bit late, but have you tried lightly tapping the power button? (not keeping it pushed down for 5 seconds, but just a gentle push?)

Comment: @fabby I think I accidentally added a repo for 15 and then apt replaced and deleted a bunch of necessary things.  I had been meaning to put my drives in a raid anyway so it was a good push to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If it goes far as halting, then it may be a problem with your hardware, since halting is actually telling the computer to shutdown, if it fails, then the computer must have failed to receive the message. Since it displays a black screen, we know it sended the request and since it has nothing to do, it just prints a black screen. It may be and can be a extremely high chance it is your hardware.
Hope i answered your question.

Comment: I'm not sure what exacting constitutes halting but I don't think it is doing that.  The login screen is a GUI not black screen.  Also a hardware problem doesn't explain `command not found`

Comment: BIOS. also, halting is technically shutdowning, or halt is shutdown.

Comment: Ok then it definitely isn't halting as it doesn't go to BIOS.  Keep in mind that it won't restart either.

Comment: Problem with Ubuntu then. I guess try to reinstall it with a backup (IF NEEDED!). To shutdown and restart you have to actually tell the hardware to do that, so to shutdown forcely you hold the power button until it shuts down, to force reboot you may force shutdown and turn it back on if you dont have a button for that, if none of these work, then it is the the hardware and or harddrive messing up.

Comment: Having to reinstall the OS seems like a pretty extreme step.  I'll wait for others.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: It's funny this is the answer and this has a -1.